# Generalization of any product similar to the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, products, arithmetic-progressions

So, the Gamma function generalizes the following product:
$$n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot..........n$$
Because it is only defined when $n$ is a natural number.
But I thought about the following product:
$$n{$}=1\cdot (1+d)\cdot (1+2d) \cdot..................n$$
Clearly this product is also defined only when $n$ is of the form $1+kd$ where $k$ is a natural number. Can this product also be generalized when $n$ is not of that form?
For example, the product:
$$f(n)=1\cdot 1.3\cdot 1.6\cdot 1.9\cdot 2.2......n$$
Clearly, this product is only defined when $n$ is of the form $1+0.3k$. Can this product be generalized?

Comment: is $d$ a rational number?

Comment: @mrnovice Does it matter? When $d=1$ we get our usual factorial function whose generalization is the gamma function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_k-symbol

Comment: @Chappers Thanks. I think that'll do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chappers commented$$P_n=\prod_{i=0}^n(1+id)=d^n \left(1+\frac{1}{d}\right)_n$$ where appears Pochhammer symbol.

This can also be expressed in terms of the gamma function $$P_n=d^n\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+1+\frac{1}{d}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{1}{d}\right)}$$